# Mysql spatial within triangle strange result

Tags: mysql, spatial

Im very new to spatial db stuff and don't understand this result:

```
mysql> select astext(LOC), Within(LOC, GeomFromText('Polygon((1 1,20 1,1 20,1 1))') ) FROM events;
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| astext(LOC)  | Within(LOC, GeomFromText('Polygon((1 1,20 1,1 20,1 1))') ) |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| POINT(10 5)  |                                                          1 |
| POINT(20 20) |                                                          1 |
| POINT(30 30) |                                                          0 |
+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I think what i have queried for is the contents of a right angle triangle 1,1 20,1 1,20 and for that reason id expect that 20,20 would not be within it. Im i not getting this right?

Cheers!
Nic

Comment: That's really interesting! What's your MySQL version?

Comment: You might find this user defined function useful [GISWithin](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?23,286574,286574)

Comment: Its MySQL 5.5, ife just discovered that MySQL doesn't fully support the within function for non-rectangular shapes, it will return any results in the enclosing rectangle or envelope.

Comment: So as my project is pretty young, im going to switch to PostGIS, good writeup here: http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/introduction.html

Comment: good choice and good luck.